# How to add new list not to replace the list

Tags: jquery

I have a listing, which this list will increase when the user add new. Currently, when user click add button, it will replace the old one with the new one, I want to remain the old value, and add the new value when user click Add button.

I know something to do at this part, but I don't have any idea on how to do it. Please help, thanks.

```
    if(radio == '1'){
        $( "#summary" ).html( "<li class='holi'>Every Week</li>" ); 
    }
```

[Add New List](http://jsfiddle.net/gJtt6/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```
$( "#summary" ).append( "<li class='holi'>Every Week</li>" );
```

[Fiddel Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gJtt6/6/)

Answer (score 2):

use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to append to the list.

This assumes `#summary` is the `ul` you want to add to. If, instead, it is the containing `div`, you can modify the selector to `$("#summary ul")`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wKJnP/)

Answer (score 0):

Inside li tag make two span, one for content and one for edit link

```
$('.editlinkclass').on('click',function(){

//this will give you content span and you can do whatever you want to do with this
$(this).prev();
})
```

Comment: you mean something like this right?   
$( "#summary" ).append( "<li class='holi'><span>Every Week "+day+"</span><span class='sLink' id='editHoliday" + now.toString() + "'>EDIT</span></li>" );
but i not get it what to do with the code that u post?

Comment: don't was id just use class

Comment: or for testing use $(this).html() as alert then use prev() and use html() to see what that is returning