# How can I add edit button with unique id on append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still working on my code, which is related to my previous question [How to add new list not to replace the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723224/how-to-add-new-list-not-to-replace-the-list) . I already get answer for that question, but another problem is, I need to add EDIT button/link for each listing. Which is this button/link will open the same Modal Window. I did try something like this [Edit Button for each listing](http://jsfiddle.net/gJtt6/11/), but it's not opening the Modal Window on click, might be because of the id is not unique. I have no idea on how to make the id unique in jquery. Pleas help.

```
     $( '#saveHoliday')
  .click(function() {
    var radio = $('#s1').val();
    var week = $('#s2').val();
    var day = $('#s3').val();

    $( "#dialog-form-holiday" ).dialog( "close" );
    $("html,body").css("overflow","auto");
    if(radio == '1'){
        $( "#summary" ).append( "<li class='holi'>Every Week&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='button_form' id='editHoliday2' style='cursor:pointer;'>EDIT</span></li>" );    
    }   
    else if(radio == '2'){
        $( "#summary" ).append( "<li class='holi'>By Week&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='button_form' id='editHoliday3' style='cursor:pointer;'>EDIT</span></li>" );   
    }
});
```

Comment: WHat do you mean the "id is not unique" -- ID's **must** be unique!

Comment: @tymeJV yes, I know id must be unique, but I have no idea on how to make it unique, since I'm new in jquery, so I don't have idea on how to manipulate the code to make the id unique

Comment: Can you edit the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

One technique is to use a timestamp to make the id unique:

```
var now = (new Date()).getTime();

$( "#summary" ).append( "<li class='holi'>Every Week&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='button_form' id='editHoliday" + now.toString() + "' style='cursor:pointer;'>EDIT</span></li>" );
```

You could also re-write your routine to actually create the elements, rather than generating the markup for them:

```
$('#saveHoliday').click(function (e) {
    var radio = $('#s1').val(),
        week = $('#s2').val(),
        day = $('#s3').val(),
        now = (new Date()).getTime(),
        edit = $('<span />').addClass('button_form').attr('id', 'editHoliday' + now.toString()).css('cursor','pointer').text('EDIT'),
        li = $('<li />').addClass('holi'),
        text = $(document.createTextNode(''));
    $( "#dialog-form-holiday" ).dialog( "close" );
    $("html,body").css("overflow","auto");
    if(radio == '1') {
        text.html('Every Week&nbsp;&nbsp;');
        li.append(text).append(edit);
        $('#summary').append(li);
    } else if(radio == '2') {
        text.text('By Week');
        li.append(text);
        $('#summary').append(li);
    }
});
```

This is usually a much better practice as it makes your code less brittle. You also don't have to worry about closing elements in markup and it makes it easier to set attributes without resorting to string concatenation.

**UPDATE**:

The specific problem you are having is that your click handler is only bound to elements that exist on `document.ready`. Your `edit` buttons do not exist when the handler is bound.

To solve this, use `.on` to delegate the handler:

```
$(document).on('click', 'span[id^="editHoliday"]', function() {
    ...
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gJtt6/16/

**UPDATE**:

For giggles, here's a demo for your specific fiddle that uses classes instead of ids (so no need for uniqueness): http://jsfiddle.net/gJtt6/17/

Comment: i did try your code, and it's generate unique id, but still the modal window not showing. Now i'm wonder, why does id generated from jquery is not working, i did copy those html (in jquery) and hard code it in html part, and it's working, but if the html in the jquery then it's not working.  http://jsfiddle.net/gJtt6/14/